# Python's __call__ method gets multiple values - error

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

In Flask, When I render the form in a Jinja2 template (being `content = PageDownField()`, the latter a subclass of `TextAreaField`):

```
{{ form.content(class_='form-control') }}
```

I get the error:

```
__call__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'class_'
```

This stems from the following line of code (in [widget.py](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-PageDown/blob/master/flask_pagedown/widgets.py)), where `class_` has been already attributed.

```
html = super(PageDown, self).__call__(field, id = 'flask-pagedown-' + field.name, class_ = 'flask-pagedown-input', **kwargs)
```

The quick and dirt solution is to modify `PageDown`class of the Flask extension.

Is there a more elegant way to solve the problem ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this CSS class is important for you, I'm afraid you have to code your own widget as there are many other things that are hard-coded in this file (like other CSS classes in the pre and post HTML strings).

```py
from wtforms.widgets import HTMLString, TextArea

pagedown_pre_html = '''
<div class="form-group">
'''

pagedown_post_html = '''
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
f = function() {
    if (typeof flask_pagedown_converter === "undefined")
        flask_pagedown_converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter().makeHtml;
    var textarea = document.getElementById("flask-pagedown-%s");
    var preview = document.createElement('div');
    preview.className = 'help-block';
    textarea.parentNode.insertBefore(preview, textarea.nextSibling);
    textarea.onkeyup = function() { preview.innerHTML = flask_pagedown_converter(textarea.value); }
    textarea.onkeyup.call(textarea);
}
if (document.readyState === 'complete') 
    f();
else if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", f, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", f);
else
    f();
</script>
'''

class PageDownBootstrap(TextArea):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        html = super(PageDownBootstrap, self).__call__(field, id = 'flask-pagedown-' + field.name, class_ = 'form-control', **kwargs)
        return HTMLString(pagedown_pre_html + html + pagedown_post_html % field.name)
```

*Note the replacement at line 15 of the class for the preview block, which may not be what you want. Change it to your needs.*

Another solution would be to use the LESS form of Bootstrap (I guess it's where the `form-control` comes from) and make the `flask-pagedown*` classes inherit the right classes from Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably already a `class_` value in `kwargs`.

Try this:

```
kwargs.update(class_='flask-pagedown-input', id='flask-pagedown-' + field.name)
html = super(PageDown, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The OP is aware that the class_ attribute is already given. He/She looks for an elegant way to solve the problem.